# carousel not fitting to the screen in the mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel on my website and it doesn't fit the mobile screens and the images move outside the screen resolution. When I check the for the responsiveness in the browser it displays correctly.

Down below is the image of how it is displayed on the mobile screen

[image]

When I check the responsiveness in the browser it is displayed as below

[image: image2]

This is the code I have

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul> -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images\home_banners\banner1.png" alt="top international schools in bangalore">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images\home_banners\banner2.png" alt="best cbse schools in bangalore south">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images\home_banners\banner3.png" alt="schools in bangalore icse">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images\home_banners\banner4.png" alt="best cbse schools in bangalore south">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images\home_banners\banner5.png" alt="schools in bangalore icse">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the `CSS` i have

```
#demo {
    top: 95px;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    /*width: auto !important;*/
    height: auto;
    width: 100% !important;
     /*height: 100%; */
    /* height: 500px; */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `img-fluid` class in your `img` tag.

```css
#demo {
  top: 95px;
}

.carousel-inner img {
  /*width: auto !important;*/
  height: auto;
  width: 100% !important;
  /*height: 100%; */
  /* height: 500px; */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul> -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1" alt="top international schools in bangalore">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2" alt="best cbse schools in bangalore south">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3" alt="schools in bangalore icse">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=4" alt="best cbse schools in bangalore south">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=5" alt="schools in bangalore icse">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```